# LPR vs Print Dialog. How to set lpr settings like in Print Dialog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, cups, lpr

I have problem with printing photos.
There are differences between printing via GUI(print dialog/ctrl+p) and via `lpr`

I need correct printing via terminal, how can i do it?

[two photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdY7Q.jpg)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i changed title, now better? it's my 1st question

Comment: You're welcome, but stackoverflow is a programming question site. Your question would better fit on superuser (http://superuser.com/)